# Round icon of Media Item on Android Auto

Tags: android, android-auto

I have tried to implement how to round any thumb from my database(which is used to being Square) on the Icon attribute of Media Item on Android Auto. But there is occurred asynchronously between Glide and building a list of Media Item before sending to be presented for the user.

So there is any way appreciate to do this. Any help is a big thanks to me.

Comment: removing people as the issue isn't caused by it.